# track old data in android application

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I'm trying to develop android application but have a problem with application logic 
the application loads data from server using RestFul web service and show it in application but when close application and open it without internet connection there is no data loaded  application become blank application without any data, the main problem how to track old data , can i use sqlite to solve this problem or there are any 
solution ?

Comment: yes offcourse, u have to use Sqlite database to store Data locally by the time you want to use Offline you can Load Data from Sqlite Tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small amounts of data, you can use SharedPreferences:

```
//put values
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaulSharedPreferences(context);
Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putString("Key", "Value");
edit.commit();
...
//get values:
String myString = sp.getString("Key", "DefaultValue");
```

For larger amounts, you should use database. Android supports quite decent ORM library, called [ORMLite.](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/) Visit their site for samples, as it would take too much space pasting complete sample here.